# A windows user - dummy guide to get a repository deployed from a mac

Tags: git, github

I come from a windows background trying to move to a mac/github environment. So please if this is basic stuff please forgive me.

I have developed an application and its sitting with in my projects folder location

> ~/myname/projects/mygreatproject

I have opened the github site and created the repository. Within terminal I have done

> git init
>   
>  git add README.md
>   
> git commit -m "first commit"
>   
> ..etc
>   I can see the first commit within github.

What do I need to do to take my folder where I have developed my application's code and get it pushed to git?
I have read the docs but maybe I am used to using a gui I dont understand what to do.

From the documentation there is allot of information about creating repositories but I can't seem to find any information about taking a directory and uploading it to github

Any help would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Did you add the Github repository as a remote? (They give you instructions for this when you create it)? have you done a `git push origin master` from your local repository to send your changes to this remote?

Comment: Hey Abizem umm I think I have. 
No I haven't done a push origin master. I will try that now

Comment: -1 as the question appears to be answered by [github's own help](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo#step-3-push-your-commit). If that's not the answer, the question isn't obvious.

Comment: @AD7six If we -1 every question on StackOverflow that has an answer somewhere on the internet, we wouldn't have many questions with a positive score.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the git commands you mention when the current directory is `~/myname/projects/mygreatproject`, to create the local repository there.

Then you just do `git add .` and `git commit` to commit all your files and `git push` to get it to github.

So:

```
cd ~/myname/projects/mygreatproject
git init
[... all the initialization that allowed you to see the first commit within github ...]
git add .
git commit -m "added my great application"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Github assumes you are starting a whole new project what you just did was commiting a brand new `README` file and pushing it to github.

To add all your files to the staging area first you `cd` to your project location. Then you use `git add .` and then to create a commit out of the files in staging area you have to use `git commit -m 'initial commit'`. Usually first commit adding all files is called initial commit. After creating the commit you have to push it to github servers with `git push origin master`.

As a general summary `git add` adds files to staging area, `git commit` creates a "snapshot" which is called a commit, `-m` switch lets you give `git commit` a message from commandline, and `git push origin master` pushes your changes on **master** branch to the remote called **origin**.

The git [book](http://git-scm.com/book) by Scott Chacon is a great read for the beginners.